# Python M2Crypto's AES 128 Encryption Different From PHP's Mcrypt

Tags: python, django, m2crypto

Here is my Python code, I can successfully encrypt and decrypt using M2Crypto:

```
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
import M2Crypto

class AESEncryptionService(object):
    def encrypt(self, key, msg):
        return self.__cipher(key, msg, 1)

    def decrypt(self, key, msg):
        try:
            decrypted = self.__cipher(key, msg, 0)
            return decrypted
        except:
            return False

    def __cipher(self, key, msg, op):
        iv = '\0' * 16
        iv.encode('ascii')
        cipher = M2Crypto.EVP.Cipher(alg='aes_128_cbc', key=key, iv=iv, op=op)
        v = cipher.update(msg)
        v = v + cipher.final()
        del cipher
        return v

enc_service = AESEncryptionService()
cipher = b64encode(enc_service.encrypt("FD496E240E7822552BC0D63C03AB7ABB", "Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello"))

print cipher

plaintext = enc_service.decrypt("FD496E240E7822552BC0D63C03AB7ABB", b64decode(cipher))

print plaintext
```

Outputs:

```
oMkdgXOy49VvvbQksxuhBq3YqJWrEw++lZO3ZMYYyo6T7JpK+Ovp+tdm+FrVGPnN
Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello
```

I have written a simple test script in PHP hoping to get the same results:

```
<?php

$key = 'FD496E240E7822552BC0D63C03AB7ABB';
$plain = 'Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello';
$iv = '0000000000000000';

$cipher = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $plain, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

$plain = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $cipher, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

echo base64_encode($cipher), '<br>';
echo $plain;
```

Outputs:

```
v5QinnNaEkn8myZa31Ikl5DrrtSXrhebDERJz4uqUgWMvbZ3datyCbm9WHPGlAo7
Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello
```

Can you help me fix the Python code to output the same as PHP? I know PHP's implementation of AES is correct as I can decrypt it in .NET. The string outputted by M2Crypto Python library cannot be decrypted in .NET.

I think it might have something to do with padding.

M2Crypto.EVP.Cipher has padding parameter. I have tried setting it to 1, 2, 3, 128 but it doesn't seem to affect the cipher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP `$iv` appears to be a string of ASCII zeros (so, byte `0x30`), where in the python `iv` you appear to be using literal `0x00` bytes.

**EDIT**

You also appear to be passing the ciphertext through `b64encode` and `b64decode`.  Are you quite sure these are exact inverses?  No line breaks, formatting, trailing new lines, etc?

Comment: I tried changing that. Python then produces vC1aH7bRFYdiBIUrqKCAwaqiWr1iB7zOuA2LTF6/dKBiA0nOq/lSseD8fNg90PsV which is still different.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have fixed the iv as well as removed the line that was base 64 decoding the key. Now it outputs WBIvyV6Q/ceRP8YRkkSqeJ0q196xRMnS7Jn/3yg4F5uxPcxb6/o+J37prXQ+HdYt - still different.

Comment: Now I got oMkdgXOy49VvvbQksxuhBq3YqJWrEw++lZO3ZMYYyo6T7JpK+Ovp+tdm+FrVGPnN - any other ideas? What could still be different?

Answer (score 0):

Quick googling revealed the following snippet: http://www.example-code.com/python/crypt2_aes_matchPhp.asp

Maybe worth giving it a try?